# complex arel query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I have a model where an article can have multiple tags (and a tag multiple articles). Article has two subclasses, product and kit. Products have a category, kits have not.

How can I get all articles (both kits and products) of a certain tag (I know the tag.id) , with the product's category loaded (avoiding a n+1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your associations are already setup (i.e. tag has_many :articles through article_tags, etc.), if you're using Rails 3, you can use #includes when you do your find. Move your belongs_to :category to your Article class (yes, it's semantically okay to do so), then:

```
@tag = Tag.first
@tag.articles.includes(:category)
```

Should work.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not. Association named 'categories' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it? Articles have no categories, only products do.

Comment: ah, I see, you put categories to articles first, but this would be semantically correct, but not domain wise. Kits consist of multiple articles, which can have different categories in return.

Comment: What I did in the end, was pre fetching all categories (they are few) and then have the 1st level cache deal with the n+1. Works without a problem. Maybe not the best thing to do, but seems to perform ok.